# Represent date of (1,1,1)

Tags: c++, boost

How can I use boost gregorian date to represent a date like this ?

C# works like this

```
Datetime d=new Datetime(1,1,1);
```

how boost works then ?

Comment: It isn't boost, but it will represent `year{1}/jan/1`: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html):

> The implemented calendar is a "proleptic Gregorian calendar" which extends dates back prior to the Gregorian Calendar's first adoption in 1582. **The current implementation supports dates in the range 1400-Jan-01** to 9999-Dec-31

You can't represent the year 1 with a `boost::gregorian::date`.

Comment: Can you re-implement it for me please ? I need 1,1,1 not 1400,1,1

Comment: @MegumiBear You mean, can I rewrite some library I didn't write to do something you need it to do that it explicitly doesn't support?

Comment: If I would want to initialize date(1,1,1), what can I do then to get the correct result returned ?